# javascript - geolocation not working in codepen

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I'm trying to implement a simple weather app in codepen. The app works fine on localhost 
It asks for permission to use navigator.geolocation and if accepted it shows the weather,
but on codepen it's not even asking for permission.

here is the link

http://codepen.io/asamolion/pen/BzWLVe

Here is the JS function

```
function getWeather() {
    'use strict';
    $('#getWeatherButton').hide();
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=53ac88144e6ee627ad0ed85277545ff9';
            //            var url = 'example.js';
            var apiCall = url + '&lat=' + position.coords.latitude + '&lon=' + position.coords.longitude;
            //            window.location.href = apiCall;
            $.getJSON(apiCall, function (json) {
                setSkycon(parseInt(json.weather[0].id, 10));
                $('#location').html(json.name + ', ' + json.sys.country);
                var temp = (Math.round((json.main.temp - 273.15) * 100) / 100);
                $('#temp').html(temp + '<span id="degree">&deg;</span><span id="FC" onclick="convert()">C</span>');
                $('#condition').html(json.weather[0].main);
            });

        });
    }
};
```

Can anybody tell me why codepen is not asking for permission?

Answer (score 11):

I had this same problem on the same challenge. Simply prepend your codepen with https instead of http and you'll be fine.

Like this:

https://codepen.io/crownedjitter/pen/AXzdvQ

if you want to use this:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
```

in Chrome.

Comment: I used a different geolocation API. Particularly ip-api.com as I found it to be easier. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I find navigator.geolocation to be much more accurate.  For example, your app places me in a city 50 miles aways from where I actually live.

Comment: @Darush Works for me.

Answer (score 3):

According to the console in Chrome:

> getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.

There's more details here: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins  Essentially Chrome only wants to send location information over HTTPS.  However, in order to allow developers to test they treat `localhost` as if it were a secure network.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Chrome 50, Chrome stopped supporting geolocation on unsecured protocols.
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only