# Codepen not recognizing navigator

Tags: geolocation, navigator, codepen

I'm trying to get the longitude and latitude of the user but I'm seeing that in Codepen the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

if(navigator.geolocation){

 function success(position){
 var lat = position.coords.latitude;
 var long = position.coords.longitude;
 $("p").html("latitude: " + lat + "<br>longitude: " + long); 
    };

function failure(){
  $("p").html("Not working");
  };

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success,failure);
};

 });
```

Output:

```
Not Working
```

So, is there a way around it or do I have to use another API for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a repeat of [javascript - geolocation not working in codepen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066541/javascript-geolocation-not-working-in-codepen).

Chrome excerpt:

> getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.